# Store a CSV into an array, search that array for a key then return 4th value within that key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have completely re-written this question:

This is database.csv:

```
barcode,ScQty,      Name     , Qty ,Code
123456 ,  3  ,Rothmans Blue  , 40  ,RB44
234567 ,  2  ,Rothmans Red   , 40  ,RB30
345678 ,  2  ,Rothmans Green , 40  ,RB20
456789 ,  2  ,Rothmans Purple, 40  ,RB10
567890 ,  2  ,Rothmans Orange, 40  ,RB55
```

I'm trying to...

1. Store a CSV file into an array
2. Search through it with a posted html form value.
3. If the value is found within one of the array keys return the 4th value in that Key.

Code for this:

```
$post = $_POST["barcode"];
$dbcsv = fopen('databases/database.csv', 'r');
$csvArray = array();
while(! feof($dbcsv))
  {
      $csvArray[]  = fgetcsv($dbcsv);
  }
fclose($dbcsv);
$searchf = preg_grep( $post, array_keys($csvArray));
$result = $csvArray[$searchf];
echo "Data Input: ";
echo $post;
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>Database: ";
print_r($csvArray);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>Key Used: ";
print_r($searchf);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/> Array Search Result: ";
print_r($result);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>4th Array Value: ";
$final = $result[+4];
print_r($final);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>Exploded Array: ";
print_r($exparr);
```

Results:

```
Data Input: 234567

Database: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 123456 [1] => 3 [2] => Rothmans Blue [3] => 40 [4] => RB44 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 234567 [1] => 2 [2] => Rothmans Red [3] => 40 [4] => RB30 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 345678 [1] => 2 [2] => Rothmans Green [3] => 40 [4] => RB20 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 456789 [1] => 2 [2] => Rothmans Purple [3] => 40 [4] => RB10 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 567890 [1] => 2 [2] => Rothmans Orange [3] => 40 [4] => RB55 ) )

Key Used:

Array Search Result: Array ( [0] => 123456 [1] => 3 [2] => Rothmans Blue [3] => 40 [4] => RB44 )

4th Array Value: RB44
```

As you can see, the $searchf variable is not returning correctly.. I cannot work out why?? It is constantly returing 0. Please help...

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? Do you get error messages?

Comment: Hey Tim, I've completely re-written the question... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read CSV file and store it in array code

```
$file = fopen("databases/database.csv","r");
$csvArray = array();
while(! feof($file))
  {
      $csvArray[]  = fgetcsv($file);
  }

fclose($file);
```

After that you can do search in `$csvArray`

**Search Function**

```
function searchForId($id, $array)
{
   foreach ($array as $key => $val)
   {
        if (in_array($id, $val))
        {
            return $key;
        }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: You broke my php page... page is just constantly loading.

Comment: What is size of your database.csv? and how many rows in that csv?

Comment: i realised it was my fault, I was still using 'file' rather than 'fopen'. Give me a second and I will re-write the rest of the code to see if it works :)

Comment: no...     $result = array_search('123456', $csvArray);
This array search is not finding the key from that array? it returns 'null'.

Comment: $result = array_search($post, $csvArray);

Comment: Updated ans for the search function you can call function like  `searchForId('123456', $csvArray)`

Comment: Hey Mitul, this is not going to change the result, it still doesn't search.. I have updated the question with the latest code I have, $searchf is still returning null...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91996/discussion-between-mitul-and-atomapps).